# List the oldest employee who is not a supervisor

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB Fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhEj2sAgdTMABBkCtJvmoC/0#&togetherjs=z3CKywAccH)**

```
SELECT Fname,Lname
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Bdate=(MaxBdate)
GROUP BY Fname,Lname
```

I tried it this way but does not work.

Comment: You need to provide sample data and desired results.  How do you know who is not a supervisor?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhEj2sAgdTMABBkCtJvmoC/0#&togetherjs=z3CKywAccH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your fiddle, assuming that supervisors have `NULL` in column `Super_ssn`, 
 I think this will work:

```
SELECT FName, Lname 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE 
  Super_ssn IS NOT NULL
  AND
  Bdate = (SELECT MIN(Bdate) FROM EMPLOYEE
           WHERE Super_ssn IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume an employee (non-supervisor) is one whose ssn is not in the supervisor ssn column.

The oldest can be derived from the `min` windowing function.

```
with employees_only as (
  select e.*, min (bdate) over (partition by 1) as min_bdate
  from employee e
  where not exists (
    select null
    from employee s
    where s.super_ssn = e.ssn
  )
)
select fname, lname
from employees_only
where bdate = min_bdate
```